# MySQL multi source replication

Tags: mysql, server

Can somebody write me step by step how to make multi source replication. I read a lot of info about it but i have a problem with gtid-mode.  I turn on gtid-mode in my.ini file on the master computer but when i make dump on  databases i got error with gtid executed need to be empty.

Comment: Could you please post your error in full, and your `my.ini` file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute:

```
slave> reset master;
slave> source dump.sql;
slave> start slave;
slave> show slave statusG
[...]
Slave_IO_Running: Yes
Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
[...]
```

Comment: When i try to open a source i got error : Incorrect information in file '\mysql\gtid_executed.frm'

Comment: I don't know ho to use gtid_executed   gtid_purged  and how to set Retrieved_Gtid_SET:

Comment: are you sure that you need gtid-mode enabled ?

Comment: Yeah i write in my.ini file  gtid-mode=on

Answer (score -1):

10:53:52 Restoring C:\Users\KasiSTD\Desktop\master3-1.sql Running: mysql.exe --defaults-file="c:\users\kasistd\appdata\local\temp\tmpmw0avv.cnf" --protocol=tcp --host=localhost --user=root --port=3306 --default-character-set=utf8 --comments < "C:\Users\KasiSTD\Desktop\master3-1.sql" ERROR 1840 (HY000) at line 26: @@GLOBAL.GTID_PURGED can only be set when @@GLOBAL.GTID_EXECUTED is empty. Operation failed with exitcode 1 10:53:53 Import of C:\Users\KasiSTD\Desktop\master3-1.sql has finished with 1 errors

This is error from mysql server 5.7 when i try to make import backup file

This is my.ini file only changes  in [mysqld]   log-bin=mysql-bin  binlog-do-db=master3   auto_increment_increment = 2   gtid-mode = on    enforce-gtid-consistency = 1     Server Id    server-id=4

Comment: execute RESET MASTER on slave before loading the dump file.

Answer (score -1):

mysql> show slave status for channel 'master-joro'\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Connecting to master
                  Master_Host: 192.168.1.62
                  Master_User: joro
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000003
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 1066
               Relay_Log_File: mysql-relay-bin-master@002djoro.000001
                Relay_Log_Pos: 4
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000003
             Slave_IO_Running: Connecting
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB: id,master2,final_repl
          Replicate_Ignore_DB:
           Replicate_Do_Table:
       Replicate_Ignore_Table:
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error:
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 1066
              Relay_Log_Space: 154
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File:
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File:
           Master_SSL_CA_Path:
              Master_SSL_Cert:
            Master_SSL_Cipher:
               Master_SSL_Key:
        Seconds_Behind_Master: NULL
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error:
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error:
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids:
             Master_Server_Id: 0
                  Master_UUID:
             Master_Info_File: mysql.slave_master_info
                    SQL_Delay: 0
          SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
      Slave_SQL_Running_State: Slave has read all relay log; waiting for more up
dates
           Master_Retry_Count: 86400
                  Master_Bind:
      Last_IO_Error_Timestamp:
     Last_SQL_Error_Timestamp:
               Master_SSL_Crl:
           Master_SSL_Crlpath:
           Retrieved_Gtid_Set:
            Executed_Gtid_Set: 2069dbc8-2c85-11e6-b4ce-0027136c5f75:1
                Auto_Position: 0
         Replicate_Rewrite_DB:
                 Channel_Name: master-joro
           Master_TLS_Version:
1 row in set (0.00 sec)